# Object is of type unknown with AWS Cognito authentication

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to setup AWS Cognito authentication with my `react` app. When I attempt retrieve some of the values from the return object I am presented with the following error

```
Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)
```

I'm looking for ways to remedy this problem but I don't know how I would have to declare the value to fix this. The code I have so far resembles what's in the [npm documentation for AWS Cognito](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js) for cases 1 and 4.

-- Code --

```
import { AuthActionTypes, AuthState } from '../types/auth';
import * as actionTypes from '../types/actionTypes';
import { Dispatch } from 'redux';

import { RootState, RootActionTypes } from '../index.';
import cognitoSignIn from '../../util/SignIn/SignIn';
import cognitoSignUp from '../../util/SignUp/SignUp';



export const authStart = (): AuthActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_START
    };
};

export const authSuccess = ( token: string, userId: string ): AuthActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_SUCCESS,
        idToken: token,
        userId: userId
    };
};

export const authFail = ( error: Error ): AuthActionTypes => {
    return {
        type: actionTypes.AUTH_FAIL,
        error: error
    };
};

export const auth = (email: string, password: string, loginMethod: string) => {
    return ( dispatch: Dispatch<RootActionTypes>, getState: () => RootState) => {
        dispatch(authStart());

        if (loginMethod === "SignUp") {
            cognitoSignUp( email, password );
        } else if ( loginMethod === "SignIn" ) {
            cognitoSignIn( email, password ).then(
                ( response ) => { /* HERE IS THE PROBLEM */
                    dispatch(authSuccess(response.idToken.jwtToken, response.accessToken.payload.client_id));
            }).catch(
                ( err ) => {
                    console.log(err.message);
                    dispatch(authFail(err.message));
                }
            );
        };        
    };
};
```

The `cognitoSignIn` can be found in `SignIn.ts` and is the following:

```
import { AuthenticationDetails, CognitoUserPool, CognitoUser } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

const cognitoSignIn = (email: string, password: string) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const authenticationData = {
        Username: email,
        Password: password
    };

    const authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails( authenticationData );
   
    const poolData = {
        UserPoolId : XXXXXXXX,
        ClientId : XXXXXXXX
    };  
    const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    
    const userData = {
        Username: email,
        Pool: userPool
    };

    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser( userData );
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: result => {
            resolve(result);
        },
        onFailure: err => {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
});

export default cognitoSignIn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the Promise resolve type in `SignIn.ts`.

The least intrusive option is to import `CognitoUserSession` and instead of creating a `Promise`, create a `Promise<CognitoUserSession>`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=63&pln=1&pc=81#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-jPYVZp0ZpCuogMXiOFSXKIQrgXIARly6snMRNq5Awlg1hsLWEIuLJS5rteVVhk+wqMhyyMABUIAAa1wVJzzcBw3B+TxaAgIgXHA5MCBfPAAH1XG7bYaR8MoYCA0DEhSD9b2-KhOQIsDzx-GAACk8Mo3dVzqIA)

The other option is to define this using standard function. ([TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=35&ssc=58&pln=34&pc=5#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgQQK4wBYFMB2NgDGAhvhDgCJYxHAA2AzgDRwDCEA5jsDBAKr1YoABQgRazNp258BUCRy49+ggMpZ69YGTgBfOADMoEEHADkREEQBeZALQEF028AAmufDACetgFb1TANwAUET0njgEBqgRpDhwDlI8KsCcAJI4ABRYlnQAXHD0MFDAOOzMYKH0AO7QLvmFxaUAlPlCRiDAAgA8kooyquqaZAB8iEFwE-FkhXBE6Nh4hCRaFCREcAC8Y5M7cMpQOBZY+dk04uO7E0KVNVB1cBUaty4XEzrBr1M4M3OY7kuxSjUOj0TZwHBYKooeb-YiAqhnegZX4LfBwlbkNZND47BzfeCQMSY6hghCfHb7ERiVL3ABEAA1GUzGbTGOTJixaMB3DT8gzmUzaZ93p88TNULIqbQwRCob1pJTRLQMoTaMSiNigqLpvAJYJ1aT2RN9ocQMc4Kc6GzLlclfk9cIlcKcZMxfAEn19jLIaxHEpZBkHerNTsoFRUAdwT62sZOlgMhkw-QxAA3LDMMM+LAEGBNTbDI1TRL9KAAOhRsJIWH2yJhi3RZCBiOYZJtuzIKlQBAIg3ySdQtHgG1GrbbNqTqfj-cHIbHb2tc7gZAAYmcI+bBFB89tF6GsFmc1koFBZ3OdIWdE1Neegh7pMk0plaURWXBaQAjWlNUt-TKJ9SQN8WB5sOO4TG68RcjyLhgkmgECKW7BUMg3aDAAKhAADWuAZN+bgOG41yeLQEBEC4uGlgQUF4AA+q4wS4jqcA+FUMAYdhcRbHB0xYIhVA0uxOHfkhMAAFKsYJmTXk0QA))

> You might also need to check `CognitoUserSession`, since in the latest version it uses functions rather than direct properties (and has been since there was a `index.d.ts`)